# There's any way to know if a DataGridViewCell is visible?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm making a CSV file from a DataGridView with the following code in VB.NET

```
'Process data cells
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DGX.Rows  'DGX As DataGridView    
    For Each dc As DataGridViewCell In dr.Cells
        CSV += dc.Value & Chr(9) 'TAB separated
    Next
    CSV += Environment.NewLine.ToString()
Next
```

The DataGriView is visible from the GUI but have some invisible columns and I need to make the CSV file without those columns, but without removing it from the GUI DataGridView because I will need them for posterior processing.

Comment: I would argue that tabs aren't really the same thing as commas.  =)

Comment: Yes, I know but there´s some numeric data and address on some cells, so I think the TAB is better to separate the cells data.

Comment: haha, I was just joking, glad you found an answer.  =)

Comment: I think you meant "post processing." Maybe not.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DGX.Rows
     If DGX.Columns(dc.ColumnIndex).Visible Then
         CSV += dc.Value & Chr(9) 'TAB separated
     End If
    CSV += Environment.NewLine.ToString()
Next
```